# Catch Suspend/Resume in Linux from user-space

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi, power-management

Is is possible to catch a signal from the Linux Kernel when some user is suspending from the hardware, not from some other application?

This means that, catch a signal when a user click a suspend button (or close the lid).

I saw that APM, for example, had to implement kernel and user space software to be able to handle this. It seems the kernel doesn't handle that by default.

Comment: Are you using ACPI? Usually there's a bunch of ACPI hooks somewhere in someplace like `/etc/acpi/actions` that you can modify or add code to.

Comment: @JonLin No, I'm not using any acpi daemon.

Answer (score 3):

If your distro is using pm-utils, you can add a script to `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` which gets called on suspend/resume (or hibernate/thaw) events.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I see, pm-utils just work if you use it to suspend, they don't listen to the kernel for some suspend signal. Am I right? I'm trying to turn off/on the wifi on suspend/resume.

Comment: I'm still confused.  The driver for your wifi device doesn't support suspend/resume (surely they all do by now)?  Are you asking a kernel development question?  What exactly is the problem this solution is trying to address?

Comment: Basically, when we suspend our device with wifi on, the device won't resume anymore. If I do ifconfig wlan0 down, and then suspend/resume works.

Comment: @AndyRoss Apart from pm-utils, is there any way a user process can get to know about the wakeup events from linux kernel.?

Comment: @mk.. You need some other mechanism from the Kernel. ACPI or similar. Otherwise there is no way to know it from user-space.